# convert letters to numbers or vice versa

Tags: database, oracle

TRADE_SIDE values are stored in DB with values 1 or 2. 
On the other hand, SPOT_SIDE values are stored with equivalent A and B values in DB.
I need to find a way to compare these values in the where clause when querying the DB. 1 for A and 2 for B.
Do you have an idea?

Comment: This question is a tad unclear, at least to me. Can you please provide your table(s) structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `CASE EXPRESSION` will do the trick :

```
SELECT * FROM trade_side t
INNER JOIN spot_side s
 ON(CASE WHEN t.<YourColumn> = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END = s.<YourColumn>)
```

This query will join both tables together on(1 = a,2 = b) . If you have more then 2 values, you should add another `WHEN` .